# Шаринг VK, Facebook без диалогового окна

Tags: php, javascript, vkontakte-api, facebook-api

Возникла такая проблема. Нужно реализовать кнопку "Поделиться", которая работала бы в 1 клик. Тобишь пользователь, авторизовавшийся в нужной соц сети, может одним нажатием кнопки Share, поделится нужной записью без диалоговых окон, подтверждений и т.д. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать.

Comment: Для FB есть [publish_actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-publish_actions), для VK не уверен что такое [возможно](https://vk.com/dev/api_confirm) (подробнее [здесь](https://vk.com/dev/wall.post))

Comment: А VK для standalone приложений это возможно сделать, да?

Comment: Ну народ ленивый пошёл :)  Дали же ссылку на документацию, нужно просто нажать на слово "здесь"...

Comment: А сами не могли догадаться, что вот так вот просто взять и создать пост от имени чужого человека, без его ведома - должно бы быть запрещено по соображениям безопасности? Если не от чужого, а от того акка, от которого у вас логин и пароль, то можно))

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я знаю, шаринг нельзя сделать без открытия дополнительного окна. Пользователь должен сам сделать это действие. Есть вариант публикации на стену пользователя через API, но тогда придется авторизовывать пользователя, а для этого придется открыть окно. И не все сети дают сайтам доступ к стене пользователя. В контакте это точно нельзя сделать, в фейсбуке точно можно, остальные не знаю.

Comment: А VK для standalone приложений?